# Java Build Path Entry Error: Blackberry Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, blackberry, buildpath

I have a project on one computer that I need to work on another computer. I followed the tutorial here: http://agile.csc.ncsu.edu/SEMaterials/tutorials/import_export/  to import and export the project files and transfer them via USB drive. However when I import the project I get a red exclamation mark icon on the project and an error saying:

**"The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved" and "unbound classpath container: 'JRE System Library [BlackBerry JRE 6.0.0] in project 'MyProject'"**

I am using the blackberry plugin for eclipse, installed altogether from the RIM website. For reference here: http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/javaplugin.jsp  with version 1.5.

I am very new to Java and this is my first time with eclipse so I really don't know what these errors mean even after googling for a while. I have attached a screenshot of the view from the new computer which I need to work on. Any help is appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was resulting from the fact that I did not have the Blackberry JRE 6.0.0 installed; I had JRE 7.0.0. I installed the JRE from the BB Java plug-in update site and after an Eclipse restart I was able to open the project. The link to use with Eclipse if anyone else has a similar issue is: http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/3.6/java

Answer (score 2):

From Window->Preferences menu, or Run->Run Configuration menu of BlackBerry Plugin Eclipse, add in Installed JREs the one you need:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, your post was instrumental in helping me find out what was wrong. When I try to click "Add", it states "The selected JRE does not support the current compiler compliance level of 1.6". However I was able to find a solution because I did not have Blackberry JRE 6.0.0 installed which turned out to be the issue.