# BBM integration , when checking BBM version checker

Tags: blackberry

I tried to invoke BBM client through my app.I used BBM sdk 1.3 ,it was working fine with devices containing BBM version 6.1..So to work it on other BBM version i used the BBM version checker as given in the documentation.I followed all the steps mentioned in the documentation, made core project and proxy project..But when i run proxy project in the simulator it was not working..

One more thing, even if it works then how do i package both the projects and install it on my device..

Plz help..

Comment: start your investigation reading here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081293/java-build-path-entry-error-blackberry-eclipse/9098481#9098481

Answer (score 1):

To package both the applications :-

1. Sign them.
2. Copy the .cod files in one folder
3. Upload it to the App Store.